# setAttribute() and XSS

Tags: javascript, security, xss

I'm writing a script that needs to write the current page location to the DOM, and I'm concerned about XSS. Is the following Javascript snippet safe from XSS?

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', 'http://fake.com?src=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

I know that using document.write() to accomplish the same thing is *not* safe in various browsers, but I've not seen any source discussing if using the DOM access methods is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need to use "setAttribute":

```
script.src = 'http://fake.com?src=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href);
```

I don't see where an XSS vulnerability would sneak in here. The server code at "fake.com" has to be "hardened" against weird values of that "src" parameter, I suppose, but that's going to be true no matter what your Javascript looks like.